# All polygons become transparent, how to fix?

Tags: java, opengl, opengl-compat

I did something in my project and all poly become transparent.

I downloaded my old git there all was okey, but it still transparent.

Tick event:
In render all poly drawings

```
    public void render() { 
       glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 
       glClearColor(0.925f, 0.98f, 0.988f, 1f);

       glPushMatrix();

       game.render();

       glPopMatrix();
   }
```

Last changed function:

```
public void drawModel(Vector3f camLocation) {

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

            glPushMatrix();
            glTranslated(copies[i].x, copies[i].y, copies[i].z);
            glRotatef(rotations[i], 0, 1, 0);

            texture.bind();
            glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
            glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);

            if (Stereometry.getVectorLenght(camLocation, copies[i]) < lodRange) {
                k = 0;
            } else {
                k = m.length - 1;
            }
            for (Model.Face face : m[k].getFaces()) {

                //Первая точка
                Vector3f n1 = m[k].getNormals().get(face.getNormalIndices()[0] - 1);
                glNormal3f(n1.x, n1.y, n1.z);
                if (m[k].hasTextureCoordinates() && hasText) {
                    Vector2f t1 = m[k].getTextureCoordinates().get(face.getTextureCoordinateIndices()[0] - 1);
                    glTexCoord2f(t1.x, t1.y);
                }
                Vector3f v1 = m[k].getVertices().get(face.getVertexIndices()[0] - 1);
                glVertex3f(v1.x * scale, v1.y * scale, v1.z * scale);

...2 More Vertex...

            glEnd();
            glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
            glRotatef(-rotations[i], 0, 1, 0);
            glTranslated(-copies[i].x, -copies[i].y, -copies[i].z);
        }

    }
```

How it looks: https://yadi.sk/i/D7XQhyBICB6sug

Comment: I have enabled this one, but it doesn't help. I also enabled ```GL_BLEND```. If i will remove ```glEnable(GL_BLEND);``` it will work correctly, but i need to use alpha chanels.

Comment: Set explicitly `glColor3f(1, 1, 1);` before drawing the textured mesh.

Comment: I found working git. To broke my polys i just need to remove```glPushMatrix();``` in ```drawModel()```. Launch app. Place back ```glPushMatrix();``` and it always will be transparent and i can fix only by downloading git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If texturing is enabled, then by default the color of the texel is multiplied by the current color, because by default the texture environment mode (`GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE`) is `GL_MODULATE`. See [`glTexEnv`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTexEnv.xml).

This causes that the color and the alpha channel of the texels of the texture is "mixed" by the last color which has been set by [`glColor4f`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glColor.xml).

Set a "white" color and an alpha channel of 1 before you render the texture, to solve your issue:

```java
glColor4f(1, 1, 1, 1);
```

Note, if the current color has an alpha channel below 1 and [Blending](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Blending) is enabled, this may cause an unexpected transparency effect.

An alternative solution would be to change the environment mode to `GL_REPLACE`, instead:

```java
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);
```